# How to print query result in the following way using php

Tags: php

I am not getting any idea how to print query results in the below format using php.

I have query results which gives information like the below

```
 Network Channel 
  A          X
  A          Y
  A          Z
  B          P
  B          Q
  C          R
```

I can able to show the results like above way.But now i wanna show results like below

```
Network Channel 
  A          x
             Y
             Z
  B          P
             Q
  C          R
```

Is there any way to show like above using loops

Comment: What kind of query ?? Database ?

Comment: This is not about query it's about representation in web page using php for loops. Any way it's sql query which will give me programs running on different channels under each network. But when i am going to show i need to show like above second representation.

Comment: loop through the result set, keeping track of when Network changes. - Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeah i am able to print like one........but as u said i can loop through result set first name i will display network name when same network i don't want to display. How can i do that if i am looping through result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you have results in some kind of associative array from a database.

Here is a rough idea; store the network value in a "last_network" variable, and check to see when it changes. When it changes, print it, otherwise print only the channel.

```
echo "Network  Channel";
for ($i = 0; $i < $result_qty; $i++)
{
    $this_network = $results[$i]['network'];
    $this_channel = $results[$i]['channel'];

    if ($this_network != $last_network)
    {
        echo "$this_network      $this_channel";
        $last_network = $this_network;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "      $this_channel";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have an associative array I'd suggest something like:

```
$last = '';
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
  if ($key != $last) {
    echo $key;
    $last = $key;
  }
  echo $value."\n";
}
```